# Why does the record gets inserted when commit was not issued?

Tags: mysql, transactions, commit

On running the following statements:

```
set autocommit = false;
start transaction;
insert into test_table (id,name) values('6','iqbal bano');
```

The entry gets inserted into the database, although I didn't issue the command `commit`. Is this behavior natural to `mysql`? If yes, why is it so? To my surprise, if I run 3 statements as:

```
set autocommit = false;
start transaction;
insert into test_table (id,name) values('7','chitra singh');
insert into test_table (id,name) values('8',nayaara);
```

The third statement, returns an error *(because nayaara had to wrapped inside the quotes)* but, the previous insert succeeds and entry with `id 7` is created into the database. What is the reason for this? Is this the way the transaction will proceed?

Note: Autocommit is set to false, as shown in the above statements.

Comment: @Drew Autocommit is set to `false`. Please see the edit.

Comment: Hi @SuhailGupta could you provide the output of this command? SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.global_variables 
 WHERE variable_name like '%version%';

Comment: @ShivaShinde What attribute value are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking for mysql version, storage engine (myisam or innodb), etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the auto-commit to false and the inserts go through, its part of the transaction but doesn't get committed to the database. If you were to restart the database the inserts would be lost; the transaction is rolledback since you did not say commit. However if you commit and then restart the records are not lost.

```
mysql> set autocommit=false;

    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> insert into test (id) values (5),(6),(7),(8);
    Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

    mysql> select * from test;
    +------+
    | id   |
    +------+
    |    1 |
    |    2 |
    |    3 |
    |    4 |
    |    5 |
    |    6 |
    |    7 |
    |    8 |
    +------+
    8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> exit
    Bye
mysql> select * from test;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test (id) values (5),(6),(7),(8);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    6 |
|    7 |
|    8 |
+------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Alright. But how do we see the data (which gets lost on restarting the database) when we perform the `select` statement?

Comment: I haven't investigated that. But it's lost when i think of it. However, the mysql database does have binary logging when it's setup as a master-slave db instances. So that slave can replicate data from master. It may be possible to switch on logging for a single standalone instance, and if that be the case, you can recover those records by recovering using that log or simply reverse engineering the logs to figure out what exactly happened. For master-slave replication logging may not impact performance as much I do not know how it would be for a single instance.

Comment: In case you turn on logging, you will also have problem of cleaning/deleting those logs as they occupy quite a bit of space. But its all relative depending on how many records are in the database, the schema structure etc.